# What is the best memory optimal way to store list index in byte file?

Tags: python, byte, storage

I have a list of byes:

```
bytes = [b'a', b'bb', b'ccc']
```

I need to write these bytes to file `b'abbccc'` while storing their length to be able to read specific elements from a file by their index. What is the best way (memory optimal) to do it?

Answer (score 0):

**Check this code and tell me if this is what you want!**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

bytes = [b'a', b'bb', b'ccc']

storage = bytes[0] + bytes[1] + bytes[2]
print(storage)

fir_element = storage[0:1]
print(fir_element)

sec_element = storage[1:3]
print(sec_element)

thi_element = storage[3:6]
print(thi_element)
```

Comment: I want to store each element's length in file to be able to unambiguously unpack these elements from file

Comment: You can do that with file handling, there are built-in functions for that ! for you to learn about file handling in python, check out this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/file-handling-python/)